# How long has Alice been fighting the Umbrella Corporation?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil

I'm looking for the in-universe answer to "How long has Alice (as Alice or her clones) been fighting against the Umbrella Corporation?"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Resident Evil (2002)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil_%28film%29)

- Alice spends several hours negociating the hive before being apprehended near the exit.
- She wakes up a day later in Racoon City Hospital

[Resident Evil: Apocalypse (2004)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil%3a_Apocalypse)

- Picks up right where the first movie ended, with Alice exiting the hospital
- Fights for the entire day and night
- In the morning the helicopter goes down and Alice is recovered by the Umbrella team.
- Three weeks later she awakens and escapes the Umbrella facility

[Resident Evil: Extinction (2007)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil%3a_Extinction)

- Five years after the initial outbreak the world is a wasteland.
- Alice and the motey crew band together for a few days.
- After Umbrella's attempt to apprehend Alice in Las Vegas, Alice decides to take the fight to them
- Alice discovers her clones

[Resident Evil: Afterlife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil%3a_Afterlife)

- Alice and her clones travel to Tokyo to confront Albery Wesker (presumably this takes at least a day to get from Nevada to Japan)
- The facility is destroyed and all of the clones perish
- 6 months later Alice goes to Alaska to find the supposed safezone
- After meeting up with Claire, they both decide to head to LA
- Upon defeating Wesker Alice decides to setup a safe haven on the Arcadia

**2d + 1d + 3w + 5y + 2d + 1d + 6m + 1d = 5 years, 7 months (or 6 months and 4 weeks). Give or take a few days for traveling to Japan, traveling to Las Vegas, and other unknown time frames.**

With the release of [Resident Evil Retribution](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1855325/fullcredits#cast) on September 14, 2012, no doubt Alice will spend even more time fighting the Umbrella corporation.